# Conversion from double to byte yields unexpected result

Tags: c#, double, byte

Let's consider a scenario: we have a double variable in our program representing percentage of byte value. After some action we are converting mentioned double to byte with simple range conversion `out = 2.55*original`. But what happens at 100% ?

```
double a = 100.0;
Console.WriteLine("original: {0}", a);
Console.WriteLine("original*2.55: {0}", (2.55*a));
byte b = (byte)(2.55*a);
Console.WriteLine("byte: {0}", b);
Console.WriteLine("wat -.-: {0}", (byte)(100.1 * 2.55));

>original: 100
>original*2.55: 255
>byte: 254  <------------------!!!
>wat -.-: 255
```

At the same time:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (byte)(255.0));
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (byte)(255));

>255
>255
```

What is going on? Shouldn't representation of integer in double that is result of multiplication behave same as one that was not multiplied? What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately `2.55` isn't represented exactly so `100 * 2.55 == 244.9999` (or something like that). `ToString()` will handle that but when you cast you get just integer part. Change to `byte b = (byte)Math.Round(2.55*a)` or use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: [A more palatable version](http://floating-point-gui.de/) of the [Obligatory Floating-Point Numbers Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (capitalisation is required).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
2.55 * 100.0
```

is evaluated to

```
254.99999999999997
```

which means that truncation when casting to a `byte` yields `254`.

Comment: @Deni One fix is to say `(byte)Math.Round(doubleExpression)` or maybe `(byte)(doubleExpression + 0.5)` instead of `(byte)doubleExpression`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to convert the double to a byte by using

```
a = Convert.ToByte(b);
```

Comment: You are right that `Convert.ToByte` would give a "better" result in this case since it _rounds_ its argument to the nearest integer. The conversion `(byte)doubleExpression` _truncates_. You could explain that difference in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `2.55 * 100` can not be represented as a `float`. Instead, it evaluates to `254.999999999`, which, when truncated, results in `254`.